# Database design for user account

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database-design

I'm building SaaS platform. One user can only have one account (or user account).   Which means one user has email, password, balance, tier plan.

What I'm confused is that should I separate the user account setting and the tier/balance data?

Should I make it 2 separate models: User (email, password) and Account (balance, tier, user_id)?

or make it one model: UserAccount(email, password, balance, tier, user_id) ?

I thought user model won't go through many changes in structure since its just for authentication.. But, for the account maybe there's some change in the future

Answer (score 1):

Ideal way should be to have Two Different Collections, but in your case when you're dealing with MongoDB (NoSQL DB) you should focus on Denormalization.
i.e. to keep avoid more collections & relations.

So, Having one model: UserAccount(email, password, balance, tier, user_id) is the ideal choice.

Answer (score 0):

You should split. That's called separation of concerns. You have a model for authentication and another for user details. you can add a foreign key from account to user.

Comment: I'm using NoSQL MongoDB